# TYPO3 menu with root page included.

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have a TYPO3 site with the following setup:

- rootPage
  - page1
  - page2
    - subPage1
  - page3
  - page4
    - subPage1
    - subPage2

I want to make a secondary navigation menu for page4 like this,

- page4
  - subPage1
  - subPage2

My Current typoscript;

```
lib.left-nav = HMENU
lib.left-nav.entryLevel = 1

lib.left-nav.1 = TMENU
lib.left-nav.1 {
  noBlur = 1
  wrap = <ul class="level-1"><li class="active"><a href="www.example.com">home</a></li>|</ul>
  expAll = 0
  NO.allWrap = <li>|</li>
  CUR = 1
  CUR.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="selected">|</li>
  IFSUB = 1
  IFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="has_sub">|</li>
  ACTIFSUB = 1
  ACTIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active">|</li>
  CURIFSUB = 1
  CURIFSUB.wrapItemAndSub = <li class="active-selected">|</li>
}
```

So, only page4 and subpages should be visible in the menu and page4 should be included as a menu item. 
Currently I have page 4 hardcoded into the menu for it to show, but I need to change this because this menu will be implemented on several other pages and I want it to be created dynamicaly. I have seen some people (like here: http://diaryproducts.net/about/cms/typo3/home_page_menu_navigation) use a shortcut to create a home link but I don't find that to be a good solution either.

Does anyone know how I could do this? I thought it would be easy but I have been struggling!

Comment: A shortcut is a handy solution in my experience and MUCH better than a hardcoded uid. Why do you consider the shortcut(s) a bad solution?

Comment: I agree that a shortcut is much better than hardcoded uid, the problem is that I will need this type of menu on a lot of pages and I thought I'd try to find a way to save myself the time of creating a shortcut for each one and then renaming it to the same as the parent, also problems can arise if users rename the parent and not the shortcut. And being that TYPO3's menu system is so flexible I expected there was a way to do this built in just that I was missing it.

Answer (score 1):

in your typoscript ther is no 2ndary level defined.
http://wiki.typo3.org/TSref/HMENU

```
lib.nav = HMENU
lib.nav {
  #1
  1 = TMENU
  1 {
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    NO.wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>   
  }
  #2 (copy of 1)
  2<.1
  #3 (copy of 1)
  3<.1
}
```

gl

update:
there are multiple possibilities, u can try use shortcuts in navigation, or create a typolink

```
   ... 
NO {
        doNotLinkIt = 1
        wrapItemAndSub=<li>|</li>
        stdWrap.cObject = CASE
        stdWrap.cObject {
          key.field = doktype
          default = TEXT
          default {
            typolink.parameter.field = uid
            field = title
            stdWrap.htmlSpecialChars = 1
          }
                    # 4 = shortcut
          4 = TEXT
          4 {
            field = title
            typolink.parameter.field = shortcut
          }
                    # 3 = external url
          3 = TEXT
          3 {
            field = title
            typolink.parameter.field = url
            typolink.extTarget.field = target
          }
    }
...
```

sample ([source](http://www.typo3wizard.com/de/snippets/menus/externe-links-und-shortcuts-direkt-im-menue.html))

Comment: Yes, sorry, the above is only pseudo code, I've got 4 levels and the menu works great, what I want is to get page4 to be displayed in the menu dynamicaly, without me having to hardcode it. In other words, the first menu item should be a link to the current page, similar to a "home" link.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try these out as soon as I get a chance and get back to you.